# Filtros com prioridade PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá,

Em muitas plataformas da web, vejo que existem formulários, sistemas de pesquisa, etc, onde o usuário necessita com obrigatoriedade, marcar alguns elementos, sejam eles dropdowns, checkboxes, radios buttons, mas em alguns deles, independente de estarem vazios ou não, o sistema ainda filtra e retorna o que você buscou pois alguns não necessitam preenchimento.

Minha curiosidade é saber como normalmente é feito o back-end nestas circunstâncias. Como é feito o `select` dentro do banco? Porque a única forma que imagino seria uma cadeia de `ifs` ou `switches` com PHP.

Grato.

Answer (score 0):

Se eu entendi corretamente, uma das maneiras de se fazer isso é montar a query no PHP, guardá-la em uma string e então executar. A montagem da query pode ser feita através de [substituição de texto](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.str-replace.php). Assim é possível acrescentar ou remover elementos sem quebrar a sintaxe do SQL.

Comment: Mas guarda-la e apenas ser executada caso alguma condição seja estabelecida ou verificar se a variáveis, seja por método get ou post, estão setadas e então aplicar o str_replace?